# Transferring Data to Presentation Layer using a generic

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, design-patterns

I just had my 5th assignment in a c# class. We had to use Entity Framework and LINQ to allow a console application to create, read, update, and delete contacts from a database. I tried to separate my program into 3 layers just so that I could practice with the different layers of an application. Does this code return a set of records to the console app layer in a proper fashion, or is there another way I should do it?

```
    public static List<Contact> ListContacts()
    {
        var ent = new contactsEntities();
        using (ent)
        {
            var query = from c in ent.Contacts select c;
            return query.ToList<Contact>();
        }
    }
```

My full program is here:
https://github.com/DavidG78/Assignment5_EF_LINQ

Comment: Beware of lazy-loading properties and the like - some people argue that a DTO separate from the EDM should be returned to mitigate this issue and avoid leaking details.

Comment: If you dont want to return your DB object out to the GUI, it can be sufficent to add an new class called ContractViewModel, that has the same values as your DB class. To make the mapping between your DB class and your ViewModel you can use Automapper. http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: Also, you just need `return query.ToList();`, since the generic type is determined by the Linq statement.